# Only want column to show positive values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Column A has a simple formula like B1+C1-D1.

This formula is dragged down the rest of Column A.

I only want Column A to show values that are zero or positive.

If the result of the formula is negative,  I want the cell to say 0.

Is this possible thru app-script With google sheets?   If so how would it look?

Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Why don't you use formula like =IF((B1+C1-D1)>=0,(B1+C1-D1),0) ?

Answer (score 2):

> I only want Column A to show values that are zero or positive.

You can use:

```
=MAX(B1+C1-D1,0)
```